# 2 columns, 1 with fixed width, the other varies to fit the rest of the row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple 2 block column:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="column_1"></div>
    <div class="column_2"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like `column_2` to be fixed width, lets say 60px. Both columns floating to the left. And the combined total (variable) width of columns equals the wrap total width:

```
#wrap { width: 100%; }
.column_1, .column_2 { float: left; }
.column_2 { width: 60px; }
```

Note: the wrap will change width, because it is nested inside a varying sized block.

A good example for use would be a text input inside column_1, with a button in column_2. Naturally the button stays the same size, while the input inside column_1 will stretch accordingly.

How would one go about this?

**Note:** I would prefer a CSS solution, but if that isn't really possible I'm open to a jquery one.

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/XzH43/

Comment: Are you open with the option of using javascript? Or you want to do it pure CSS? If you want to do pure CSS, check `flexbox`.

Comment: @adaam that doesn't work. If you change #container width to be bigger .column_1 remains the same.

Comment: @Zendy If js or jquery is the only way. flexbox looks like the thing, but seems to be fairly unsupported still. So I guess js is the only option?

Comment: I think the fiddle works perfect, I tried #containing width as 700 and still on adding content to .colum1 it's width increases.

Comment: @umesh weird. on FF and Chrome column_1 remains the same if i change the width of #container.

Comment: do the column1 width changes on adding content without changing width of container?
Have u tried that?

Comment: @willdanceforfun my fiddle worked for me in FF.

Comment: Sorry but I think you have both misunderstood what I am trying to do. .column_1's width is to be determined by the parent element. It doesn't change size depending on the content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how far behind you want to support the old browser. You can do some detection, if they support `flexbox` then use it, otherwise fallback with `jquery`. Javascript will always work for it, but it'll add another layer of processing. If you want to try with new `flexbox` specification, you can have a look at this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/working-with-flexbox-the-new-spec.html